# How to retrieve a nested object?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{ 
    key : "bla"
    list : [
       {id:1}, 
       {id:2}
    ]
}
```

How do I get this object: `{id:1}` ?

I tried a query like this: `db.myCollection.find({"key":"bla", "list.id":1})`

it finds the entry, but returns the complete document instead of only `{id:1}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB extract only the selected item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` operator is what you're looking for:

```
db.test.insert({key: "blah",list :[{id:1},{id:2}]})

db.test.find({'list.id' : 1},{'list.$': 1 })
#Returns:
#{ "_id" : ObjectId("521a78b342abf388fbaacf91"), "list" : [ { "id" : 1 } ] }

db.test.find({'list.id' : 2},{'list.$': 1 })
#Returns:
#{ "_id" : ObjectId("521a78b342abf388fbaacf91"), "list" : [ { "id" : 2 } ] }
```

If you don't need the _id of the document, you can exclude that too:

```
db.test.find({'list.id' : 2},{'list.$': 1 , _id: 0})
#Returns:
#{ "list" : [ { "id" : 2 } ] }
```

For more information, have a look at the documentation of the [$ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#proj._S_) and [read operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#projection) in general.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I still have to retrieve the object for "list" key (would have prefered to get directly the array), but this is probably the only way currently.